# I need to disallow certain words in my registration process

Tags: php

```
if (strtolower(strpos($_POST['username']), "host") !== FALSE) {
                    $errors[] = 'You cannot have the word HOST in your name.';
                }
```

Now this is perfect if I want to stop somebody using the name `Host Andy` For instance, but horrible if somebody creates the username `Ghost` and alike.. How do I filter it to only stop the first word being host?

EDIT:

```
    if (strtolower(strpos($_POST['username']), "host") === 0) {
    $errors[] = 'You cannot have the word HOST in your name.';
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you create a function of banned words, and use `strpos`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use preg_match to check the word based on a boundary:

```
$pattern = "/\bhost\b/i";

if(preg_match($pattern, $_POST['username']))
{
    $errors[] = 'You cannot have the word HOST in your name.';
}
```

EDIT

To match only the first word, simply remove the first word boundary:

```
$pattern = "/^host\b/i";
```

FURTHER EDIT: Adding the ^ character begins the string with the word host. That tells regex it must begin with host as a single word, case insensitive.

Comment: Can this be made to only match the start of the string?

Comment: Yes. remove the first boundary. $pattern = "/host\b/i";

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you, I shall accept your answer in 3 minutes.

Comment: @KaiQing Would this not then match something like "Ahost Andy"? Since `host\b` matches that fine

Comment: Yeah but he seems to only care about the literal word "host"

Comment: @Kai Qing A username should be banned only if 1) it starts with host 2) the host it starts with is the whole word. Ahost Andy should not be banned. Will your approach ban it?

Comment: There, adding the ^ char should force regex to begin at that word and end at the first word boundary

Answer (score 1):

if you want to stop *usernames* to be created that starts with `"host%"`, then do:

```
if (substr(ltrim(strtolower($_POST["username"])),0,4)=="host") {
   $errors[] = 'You cannot have the -starting- word HOST in your name.';
}
```

**UPDATE:**

i added the [`ltrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) just to keep things more safe against more *nasty* approaches;

feel free to remove it and instead handle trims when you passed the `"host"` case.

Finally, while its no clear, if you want to stop `"host"` but allow `"host "` (?), just change:

```
if (substr(ltrim(strtolower($_POST["username"])),0,5)=="host ") {
```

Comment: Can I use the name `Hostile Andy`?

Comment: Hostile Andy isn't going to like this.

Comment: my updated version would like `Hostile Andy` and also `Hostile Mary` but not `Host Cheap` or `"   host nasty"`... well it depends, i covered all cases i suppose..

Answer (score 0):

`stripos($_POST['username'], "host ") === 0` will be true if `host` (as in, host followed by a space) is at the start of the string and false otherwise.

If spaces before the first word are possible, you may want to use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php first.

If host with symbols before it, or host with symbols after it, at the start of a string also needs to be banned let me know.

Though, I would question why Host needs to be banned from the start of usernames. Can it be indicated in a different way? For example, only Hosts get green italicized names would make it impossible to spoof a Host.

Comment: `strtolower` will cast an integer to a string

Comment: What if I want my username to be "hostile"

Comment: Once I add that, it doesn't seem to recognize host in the username anywhere and doesn't display the error message? Am I implementing it wrong? I'll update the question.

Comment: @user2305310 How could that be possible? If the string starts with "host ", case insensitive, stripos will return 0, and 0 === 0 is true.

Comment: The reason I need to stop this, is just a precaution against people trying to imitate Hosts, therefore to stop the people who will fall for their spoofs from falling for it. May seem far fetched, but it may save somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i use to filter bad words on my site. Use it to your liking. It should point you in the right direction because it will filter only "i am a badword " and not "iamabadword".

```
function filterBadWords($str) {
    $badWordsFile = "badwords.txt";
    $badFlag = 0;
    if(!is_file($badWordsFile)) {
        echo "ERROR: file missing: ".$badWordsFile;
        exit;
    }
    else {
        $badWordsFH = fopen($badWordsFile,"r");
        $badWordsArray = explode("\n", fread($badWordsFH, filesize($badWordsFile)));
        fclose($badWordsFH);
    }
    foreach ($badWordsArray as $badWord) {
        if(!$badWord) continue;
        else {
            $regexp = "/\b".$badWord."\b/i";
            $badword_add_last_letter = $badWord.substr($badWord, -1);
            $regexp_add_last_letter = "/\b".$badword_add_last_letter."\b/i";
            if(preg_match($regexp,$str)) $badFlag = 1;
            if(preg_match($regexp_add_last_letter,$str)) $badFlag = 1;
        }
    }
    if(preg_match("/\[url/",$str)) $badFlag = 1;
    return $badFlag;
}
```

And the file badwords.txt is just a file that looks like this:

```
badword1
badword2
badword3
```

**EDIT:**

If you simply want the word HOST, then use this function:

```
function filterString($str) {
    if(preg_match("/\bhost\b/i",$str)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing me with this, I shall save it for future reference.

Comment: It looks like this could work if you simply only check to see if the first word is host, then stop.

Comment: This will see if the word "host" exists anywhere in the string. Example, "Hostile Andy" will pass without a problem and return false, but "Andy the Host" will not pass and it will return true.

Comment: Edited post to include more of what you are looking for.